# Reduce complexity of relative/canonical path? (How to eliminate ".."?)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to basically trying to convert `"dir1/dir2/../dir3"` to `"dir1/dir3"` by using a regex as follows:

```
filePath.replaceAll("^(\\w)?(<>:\"/\\|?*)//\\.\\./", "");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I know that there are many normalization rules, but I only want to apply the two rules:

```
All "." segments are removed.

If a ".." segment is preceded by a non-".." segment then both of these segments are removed. This step is repeated until it is no longer applicable.
```

I also tried:

```
result = filePath.replace("^(\\w+)\\.\\./", "");
```

but it didn't work out either

Comment: are you sure that File.getCanonicalPath() is not what you really need?

Comment: If you do wish to normalize this by hand, and use a regular expression, consider running a simpler regular expression multiple times (until the output is unchanged). Then it's just the matter of replacing "path/.." (add edge guards) with "" each phase.

Comment: no.. because I don't want all the normalization rules to be applied

Comment: @pst and what is the regex rule for that?

Comment: @pst why do you have to do this multiple times and why can't the replaceAll do it at once?

Comment: @Oleg: I could be wrong (it's been a few years since I used Java), but don't getCanonicalPath() require a valid file existing on the file system?  So, basically, you wouldn't be able to use this on an abstract path.

Comment: @xonegirlz, consider  </a/b/c/../../d/>.  You can't do this with a regular expression in a single pass because you have to count how many '..' you've removed.

Comment: @Dmitry, mind putting that as an answer and put a little bit more explanation? I am guessing you'll have to keep looping until your filePath doesn't change?

Comment: @Dmitry Beransky Yes. My assumption was that he did have access to the physical file system

Comment: @Oleg this is just a String filePath, not a real physical file system

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by counting how many .. you removed.. why do you need to count?

Comment: @xonegirlz: you only need to count if you'd want to do this within a single pass (singe regex match) because for every '..' you need to remove at most one preceding segment (and regex is not recursive).  Doing this in a loop until filePath doesn't change is essentially like counting.  So yes, using regex in a loop will work, but you can't do this with one match.

Comment: okay.. so in your case above what should /a/b/c/../../d return? is it just a/d?

Comment: and also for removing the . I assume I can do it in a single pass?

Comment: @Dmitry one last question what if it's a/../../../../d?

Comment: yes, /a/b/c/../../d should resolve to just /a/d.  and a/../../../../d should resolve to ../../../d.  However /a/../../../d is undefined.

Comment: @Dmitry how do I write a regex for that then? If you could put it up as an answer, I'll definitely accept it

Comment: you can't do this with regex alone.  that was my point.  '..' makes the grammar of paths expressions context sensitive.  Regular expressions by design only work with regular grammars.  So my original answer still stands.

Answer (score 3):

you can't use regular expressions for this (yes, simple cases like your example may work, but will quickly break down for more complex patterns).  Since you use java, take a look at [`java.net.URI.normalize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

> Normalizes this URI's path ... If a ".." segment is preceded by a non-".." segment then both of these segments are removed. This step is repeated until it is no longer applicable. ...

Comment: so there's no way to do normalization using regex?

Comment: @xonegirlz: Dmitry is right, this can't be solved with a regular expression. Almost all frameworks have dedicated methods for file path normalization, and you should use them. After all, they're tried and tested and take cases into account which you might not think of at first.